# Implementation of HFCC-E FB-29 in Python for MFCC feature extraction

Tags: python, mfcc

I was reading about different implementations of MFCC feature extraction algorithm for the audio features. I found four implementation techniques; MFCC FB-20, HTK MFCC FB-24, MFCC FB-40 & HFCC-E FB-29. And a comperative study says that HTK MFCC FB-24, MFCC FB-40 & HFCC-E FB-29 techniques perform better for speech recognition.
So I am planning to test them all for my thesis work. I have found python implementation for two of them. Well known and popular python package named `librosa` usees MFCC FB-40 & HTK MFCC FB-24 implementations. And now I am searching for python implementation of HFCC-E FB-29 technique.
Anyone can help me with this issue?

Note: I was checking another python package named `python_speech_features` but not sure about their implementation technique.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a definition of the HFCC-E FB-29 method?